# Distinta sintaxis para throw

Tags: javascript, excepciones

Tengo una duda que me ha surgido utilizando la palabra reservada **throw** de JavaScript.

Según la documentación la sintaxis es:

> throw expresión;

Ahora bien, he visto varios ejemplos utilizando throw como si fuera una llamada a una función, es decir, la expresión entre paréntesis:

```js
throw(new Error('Esto es un error'))
```

Es más, si le pasamos más de un argumento cogerá el último argumento:

```js
throw(1, 2, 3, new Error('Esto es un error'), 'El último')
```

Este comportamiento parece no estar documentado, la pregunta sería, ¿porqué no salta algún error de sintaxis?

Si la sintaxis es correcta, ¿qué sentido tiene poder pasarle tantos argumentos?

Si estoy totalmente equivocado, qué es lo que me estoy perdiendo aquí?

Comment: Todo javascript esta basado en v8 de google, este codigo de fondo invisible al usuario y el toma todos los parametros que pasamos en una funcion javascript como un array de parametros, en el cual lo mas seguro es que tome el ultimo elemento del array. en otras funciones el toma los parametros en el orden en que se asignan, eso es lo que da la flexibilidad a la que estamos acostumbrados en javascript y no se reviente por casi nada

Comment: Pero throw no es una función, es una palabra reservada.

Comment: Pero se comporta como una funcion, y v8 toma los parametros de una funcion como un array, por eso no se va a reventar

Comment: Información sobre el constructor **[Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)**

Comment: De acuerdo, @Lcop, suena lógico. Lo que no encuentro es ninguna documentación que explique esto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tiene que ver con las expresiones. Si desde la consola haces `1, 5, 7`, Javascript responde `7`. Es decir, evalúa los elementos, y devuelve el último evaluado.

Comment: @Lcop V8 engine es solo una implementación de la especificación ECMAScript por parte de Google no al revés, hay otras implementaciones como SpiderMonkey que es el motor Javascript de Firefox, Nitro Javascript en Safari... en las especificaciones de ECMAScript participan muchos ingenieros y empresas, Google es solo una de ellas.

Comment: Tienes razon @CarlosLucero no cai en cuenta de eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw no es una función, es una sentencia por lo tanto cuando haces esto

```
throw(new Error('Esto es un error'))
```

estas ejecutando la sentencia throw que va acompañada de una expresión y no una lista de parámetros por lo tanto los paréntesis del primer nivel son innecesarios y no indican la ejecución de una función sino mas bien aquí sirven como un operador de [agrupación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Grouping), por lo tanto puedes omitirlos.

```
throw new Error('Esto es un error')
```

no te confundas con la sintaxis de una función, que para ejecutarla debes usar los paréntesis y enviar una lista de parámetros

```js
function hola(nombre) {
  console.log('Hola, ' + nombre);
}

hola('Pepe'); // Esto ejecuta la función
hola 'Pepe'; // Esto es un error de sintaxis
```

Los parámetros que envías a la función son expresiones

```
hola(('Pepe')); // Esto es igual a hola('Pepe');
```

aquí el primer nivel de paréntesis ejecuta la función [hola], el segundo nivel de paréntesis sirven como operador de agrupación que resuelve al mismo valor 'Pepe'.

Las funciones en javascript pueden recibir N cantidad de parámetros, si al ejecutar envías mas parámetros de los necesarios entonces la función tomara los primeros hasta que coincida con el numero de parámetros que reciba y desecha el sobrante.

```
hola('Pepe', 'Lucho', 28); // la función [hola] solo toma 'Pepe' e ignora el resto
```

pero esto es diferente a una lista de expresiones separadas por comas como por ejemplo

```js
1, 'Hola', hola(('Pepe')), 'Lucho'; // Esto son 4 expresiones separadas por comas
function hola(nombre){console.log(nombre)}
```

La coma puede ser usada para separar expresiones que escribes en una sola linea por lo tanto es equivalente a esto.

```
1; 'Hola'; hola(('Pepe')); 'Lucho';
```

La clausula throw puede recibir un objeto Error o no, tu puedes enviar cualquier valor a throw como cadenas, números u otros objetos.

```
throw new Error('Error 404 not found');
throw 'Error 404 not found';
throw 404;
```

Entonces en tu ejemplo esta linea

```
throw(1, 2, 3, new Error('Esto es un error'), 'El último')
```

es equivalente a

```
throw 1, 2, 3, new Error('Esto es un error'), 'El último'
```

como es una expresión y no una lista de parámetros, esta expresión se resuelve al ultimo valor, en tu caso es la cadena 'El último'.

```
throw (1), (2), (3), (new Error('Esto es un error')), ('El último') // Uncaught El último
throw ((1), (2), (3), (new Error('Esto es un error')), ('El último')) // Uncaught El último
```

y por ultimo el punto y coma delimita la sentencia por lo tanto estas no son equivalentes

```js
throw 1, 2, 3, new Error('Esto es un error'), 'El último' // Uncaught El último
```

```js
throw 1; 2; 3; new Error('Esto es un error'); 'El último' // Uncaught 1
```